# the return statement is available and the compiler still asks for it

Tags: java

I have the below posted method, and as shown it return Boolean data type. I wrote the return statement but though, the compiler gives me an error saying: this method must return a result of type boolean.

Java code:

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {
    boolean found = false;

    if (arraylist.isEmpty())
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
        if (arraylist.get(i) == guess)
            return true;
        else continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `return` outside the `for` loop. The method needs to return something in case all the `if` statements fail.

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) 
{
    boolean found = false;

    if (arraylist.isEmpty()) return found;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (arraylist.get(i) == guess) found = true;
    }
    return found; // Add return here if all else fails
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do have `return` statements, but the Java compiler insists that there is a `return` statement for all possibilities of paths of execution the code might follow.  There is a possibility that the `for` loop ends and then there is no `return` statement.

Add a `return false;` statement after the end of your `for` loop.

Additionally, the `else continue;` is unnecessary, because there is nothing else to skip in the `for` loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure your method slightly based on how you written it.

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {

    if (arraylist == null || arraylist.isEmpty())
        return false;

    boolean found = false;

    for (int guessItem : arraylist) {
        if (guessItem == guess) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }

    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function with a return type, must end with a `return` statement; before closing braces.

So, the solution is:

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {
    boolean found = false;

    if (arraylist.isEmpty())
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
        if (arraylist.get(i) == guess)
            return true;
        else continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is also acceptable to include a return statement on every control path. For example, `if (a) return true; else return b;` compiles

Answer (score 0):

There is a programming style, not particular to Java, that insists that modular code should end with only one single return statement.

There are cases in which it is more perspicuous and expedient to ignore this style rule, especially when return statements at the beginning of a code block filter out error conditions early on.

Your code block is short and sweet, though ... and so the styling rule actually makes your code easier to follow and understand.  It also makes it more foolproof since you don't need to worry about the value that other return statements in your code are returning to the caller.

TL;DR:  I'd try going with this instead:

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {

    boolean found = false;

    if (!arraylist.isEmpty()) {

        for (int i=0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
            found = ((arraylist.get(i).integerValue() == guess));
            if (found) break;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Edit: I like to do the boxing and unboxing of primitives myself.  It fosters the illusion that I'm in control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your conditions are not constants so the compiler can't decide if the method will always return something. As an aside, a shorter equivalent version would be:

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {
    return arraylist.contains(guess);
}
```